# show activity inside popup window android

Tags: android, android-activity, popupwindow

I have a task to make an activity that look like facebook notification screen
please see the attached image

[image]

can any one please help me with tutorial or example that will help me to make activity looks like this ?

Comment: create layout as above and use: <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" /> in android manifest.

Comment: but this will not make it looks like the above image as it will not be shown in a specific x , y

Comment: create layout like that image.. add use padding for left, right 7 bottom, for top use image... all layout must be in center.. i think this is only way you can do that...

Comment: "show activity inside popup window android" -- this is not possible. That popup contains a `ListView` (possibly managed by a `ListFragment`), not a `ListActivity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this effect I have used a normal activity with dialog theme and set it's background to transparent, and override onAttachActivity event to set the position and width and height of my new activity as I want

Answer (score 1):

//Try this i think it may be help u

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) youractivityname.this
                        .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                View pview;
                pview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.Yourlayoutname, null);

                PopupWindow cp = new PopupWindow(pview, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
                cp.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
                cp.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                cp.update(0, 0, 500, 350);
```